# How can I write this query with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I write this query with LINQ?

```
 SELECT  OrderID, [1] T1, [2] T2, [3] T3, [4] T4, [5] T5
    FROM    (SELECT OrderId, ReportTypeId FROM OrderReport) p PIVOT
    ( COUNT(ReportTypeId) FOR ReportTypeId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) ) pvt
```

Comment: Please include your code showing what you have attempted so far.

Comment: You can't. Linq does not support `PIVOT`. To be precise, you can use Linq to call a user defined function (or even a stored procedure) that does the `PIVOT`, but you cannot write a Linq query that will generate a `PIVOT` in Linq to SQL nor Entity Framework. Other poviders may have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your query could be rewritten as a regular COUNT/CASE;

```
SELECT OrderID, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ReportTypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) T1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ReportTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) T2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ReportTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) T3,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ReportTypeId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) T4,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ReportTypeId = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) T5
FROM OrderReport
GROUP BY OrderId;
```

...which (untested) would look something like this in Linq;

```
var query = db.myTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.OrderID)
    .Select(t => new {
        OrderID = t.Key,
        T1 = t.Where(c => c.ReportTypeId == 1).Count(),
        T2 = t.Where(c => c.ReportTypeId == 2).Count(),
        T3 = t.Where(c => c.ReportTypeId == 3).Count(),
        T4 = t.Where(c => c.ReportTypeId == 4).Count(),
        T5 = t.Where(c => c.ReportTypeId == 5).Count()
    });
```